# Can't restore files from Live Recovery CD

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade

After a "normal" system update, my computer gets stuck in a flickering black screen. 
I made a Live Recovery CD and followed the "update failure" steps found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

After apt-update I get "error while moving old database out of the way. Appstream cache update failed".

How can I restore broken files?

`apt update` output:

```
Err:1 ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:2 dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable In Release Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:3 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security In Release Could not solve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial In Release Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates In Release Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48563/discussion-on-question-by-ghosts-in-my-machine-cant-restore-files-from-live-rec).

Comment: @DavidFoerster that solved the DNS issue, hoever my computer still wont boot after

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? It's easier to deal with one issue at a time than to lump them all together. Thanks.